# can i use basil.js with Hebrew

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, basil.js

im trying to run the attached script on Hebrew text (right to left) with no luck.
Any ideas?
Thanks,
Ori

http://basiljs.ch/gallery/alphabet-bars/

Comment: Looks like it won't work out of the box that way, you'll have to tweak it a bit

Comment: haha :)  so there is no escape for designers from learning code :)
It actually worked pretty good with english.

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise in which sense you are having trouble with your implementation?

Comment: Sure. This thing suppose to sort and count letters in a text-box and then present the results in a bar chart. it works great for me when using english text, but not when trying with Hebrew text.

Comment: Ok, well the English language is obviously quite close to how computers work internally, while hebrew is not... What you are trying to do is alphanumerical sorting with JavaScript. You should do a search on "alphanumerical sorting hebrew characters with JavaScript".